# GIT scanning .gitignore directories

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a server setup that deploys code with a read only git user.  We just moved one of the subdirs to the fuse S3FS which is slow but perfect for our needs.  When running git pull now it is scanning this entire directory which takes about 20 minutes when it used to take a fraction of a second.

I had a folder named uploads/ that was in git.
I removed all files (uploads/*) from git.  Git now has an empty folder named uploads/.
The network directory is mounted on uploads/.

The .gitignore is:

```
/uploads
/uploads/*
```

Any ideas on how to get GIT to not scan this directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your uploads folder in the root folder of your repository? You probably want this.

```
uploads/
```

That will ignore any folder named `uploads`.